# public/private key cryptography ( MTA Mobility )

Tags: encryption, mta, mobility

I have a question in MTA (Microsoft Technology Associate) Mobility and I want the answer to it please

The Question :

a client/server application is designed to use public/private key cryptography for secure communication between client and server , The certificate is installed on the server

when the client send message to the server which key does it use to encrypt the message ?

A)The client's private key

B)The client's public key

C)The server's private key

D)The server's public key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D.  The Client uses the server's public key to encrypt the message it wants to send to the Server.  The Server can then use its private key to decrypt the message that it was sent, because it was encrypted using that server's public key.

[More info about Public Cryptography here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HubAvQg6SPM)